# Any way to dynamically load angular directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a short fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aSg9D/

Basically, neither `<div data-foo-{{letterA}}></div>` nor `<div data-ng:model="foo-{{letterB}}"></div>` are interpolated.

I'm looking for a way to dynamically load one of several inline templates.

Pardon me if this has already been asked before, but I searched and couldn't find it.

---

I believe Radim Köhler has the correct answer. Just before it was posted, I hacked together something to load directives from another directive like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('loadTmpl', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $element.html("<div data-card-"+$attr.loadTmpl+"></div>");
            $compile($element.contents())($scope);
        }
    };
});
```

And:

```
<div data-load-tmpl="{{directiveName}}"></div>
```

I think that's the minimalist approach, but there's probably something wrong with it, so just look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's adjust it this way (the udpated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kjZ6/2/)). The view:

```
<div my-selector name="letterA"></div>
<div my-selector name="letterB"></div>
```

the controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.letterA = 'bar';
    $scope.letterB = 'baz';
}
```

And here is new directive `mySelector`, containing the selector

```
.directive('mySelector', 
  [       '$templateCache','$compile', 
  function($templateCache , $compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        name: '='
      },
      replace: true,   
      template: '',            
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

        scope.buildView = function (name) {
            var tmpl = $templateCache.get("dir-foo-" + name);
            var view = $compile(tmpl)(scope);
            elm.append(view);
        }
      },
      controller: ['$scope', function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('name', function (name) {
            scope.buildView(name);
        });
      }],          
    };
}])
.run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("dir-foo-bar", '<div data-foo-bar></div>');
    $templateCache.put("dir-foo-baz", '<div data-foo-baz></div>');
}])
```

In case you like it, all credits goes to [Render a directive inside another directive (within repeater template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479162/) and [AngularJS - Directive template dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862315/), if you don't, blame me.